# One of my results are messed up

Tags: java, eclipse

I am working on a project that has the user input the current date as well as their birthday. The whole code calculates their age as well as printing the date. For the current date it should show 11/14/2016, but instead shows 0/14/2016 and I cannot figure out where I went wrong.

Here's the code:

```
public class BroDoYouEvenAge {

    // add in try-catch statements x
    // only numeric values x
    // leap year
    // loop if invalid
    // loop if day is invalid
    // less than 1 or greater than max day x
    // add in no spaces or letters x

    // VALIDATION FOR MONTHS x
    // loop if invalid
    // same year x

    // try again x
    // loop if invalid

    static int cDay;
    static int cMonth;
    static int bYear;
    static int bMonth;
    static int bDay;

    public static void run() {
        prompt();
        retry();
    }

    public static void prompt() {
        BufferedReader delta = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        try {

            System.out.println("Please enter the current year");
            String Year = delta.readLine();
            int cYear = Integer.parseInt(Year);

            // prompts the user for the current month as a numeric value
            boolean validmonth = false;
            while(!validmonth){
            System.out.println("Please enter the current month as a numeric value");
            String Month = delta.readLine();
            int cMonth = Integer.parseInt(Month);

            if (cMonth < 1 || cMonth > 12) {
                System.out.println("Your input was invalid");
            }else{
                validmonth = true;
            }
            }

            // prompts the user for the current day as a numeric value
            boolean validday = false;

            while (!validday) {
                System.out.println("Please enter the current day as a numeric value");
                String Day = delta.readLine();
                cDay = Integer.parseInt(Day);

                if (cDay < 1) {
                    System.out.println("Your input was invalid");
                }else if (cDay > 31) {
                    System.out.println("Your input was invalid");
                }else if (cMonth == 4 && cDay > 30) {
                    System.out.println("Your answer is invalid");
                }else if (cMonth == 6 && cDay > 30) {
                    System.out.println("Your answer is invalid");
                }else if (cMonth == 9 && cDay > 30) {
                    System.out.println("Your answer is invalid");
                }else if (cMonth == 11 && cDay > 30) {
                    System.out.println("Your answer is invalid");
                }else{
                    validday = true;
                }
            }

            // prompts the user for their birth year
            boolean validYear = false;
            while(!validYear){
            System.out.println("Please enter your birth year");
            String Year2 = delta.readLine();
            bYear = Integer.parseInt(Year2);

            if (bYear > cYear) {
                System.out.println("Your answer was invalid");
            }else{
                validYear = true;
            }
        }
            // does not allow user to input a value greater than their current
            // year
            // loops if invalid

            // prompts the user for their birth month
            boolean _validmonth = false;
            while(!_validmonth){
            System.out.println("Please enter your birth month as a numeric value");
            String Month2 = delta.readLine();
            bMonth = Integer.parseInt(Month2);

            if(bMonth < 1 || bMonth> 12){
                System.out.println("Your answer was invalid");
                }else{
                    _validmonth = true;
                }
            }

            // prompts the user for their birth day
            boolean _validday = false;
            while(!_validday){
            System.out.println("Please enter the day you were born as a numeric value");
            String Day2 = delta.readLine();
             bDay = Integer.parseInt(Day2);
            // prints out collected data

            if (bMonth == 4 && bDay > 30) {
                System.out.println("Your answer is invalid");
            }else if (bMonth == 6 && bDay > 30) {
                System.out.println("Your answer is invalid");
            }else if (bMonth == 9 && bDay > 30) {
                System.out.println("Your answer is invalid");
            }else if (bMonth == 11 && bDay > 30) {
                System.out.println("Your answer is invalid");
            }else{
                _validday= true;
            }
            }

            System.out.println("The current date is " + cMonth + "/" + cDay + "/" + cYear);
            System.out.println("Your birthday is " + bMonth + "/" + bDay + "/" + bYear);

            // calculates and prints age
            if (cMonth > bMonth) {
                int age = cYear - bYear;
                System.out.println("You are " + age + " years old ");
            } else if (cMonth < bMonth) {
                int age = (cYear - bYear);
                System.out.println("You are " + age + " years old ");
            } else if (cMonth == bMonth && cDay > bDay) {
                int age = cYear - bYear;
                System.out.println("You are " + age + " years old.");
            } else if (cMonth == bMonth && cDay < bDay) {
                int age = (cYear - bYear) - 1;
                System.out.println("You are " + age + " years old. ");
            } else if (cYear == bYear) {
                System.out.println("You are not even a year old.");
            } else {

                System.out.println("Your input was invalid");
            }
        } catch (IOException IOE) {

        } catch (NumberFormatException NFE) {
            System.out.println("Please enter a numeric value without spaces, letters, or special characters");
        }
    }

    public static void retry() {
        BufferedReader delta = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        try {
            boolean valid = false;
            while (!valid) {
                System.out.println("Would you like to try again? 1) Yes or 2) No");
                System.out.println("Please enter a number");
                String retry = delta.readLine();
                int trynum = Integer.parseInt(retry);

                if (trynum < 1 || trynum > 2) {
                    System.out.println("Your input was invalid. Please enter 1 or 2.");
                    continue;
                } else if (trynum == 1) {
                    prompt();
                } else if (trynum == 2) {
                    System.out.println("Okay then.");
                    System.exit(0);
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Invalid");
                    continue;
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException IOE) {

        } catch (NumberFormatException NFE) {
            System.out.println("Please enter a number");
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Probably not your issue, but are you sure you're checking `cDay` correctly for all months?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are initializing a new cMonth variable when reading the months value on the line

```
System.out.println("Please enter the current month as a numeric value");
String Month = delta.readLine();
int cMonth = Integer.parseInt(Month);
```

Just remove the initialisation of the cMonth local variable as you want to refer to a global variable.

```
System.out.println("Please enter the current month as a numeric value");
String Month = delta.readLine();
cMonth = Integer.parseInt(Month);
```

Just to provide you the working source code I am pasting working solution:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class BroDoYouEvenAge {

    // add in try-catch statements x
    // only numeric values x
    // leap year
    // loop if invalid
    // loop if day is invalid
    // less than 1 or greater than max day x
    // add in no spaces or letters x

    // VALIDATION FOR MONTHS x
    // loop if invalid
    // same year x

    // try again x
    // loop if invalid

    static int cDay;
    static int cMonth;
    static int bYear;
    static int bMonth;
    static int bDay;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        run();
    }

    public static void run() {
        prompt();
        retry();
    }

    public static void prompt() {
        BufferedReader delta = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        try {

            System.out.println("Please enter the current year");
            String Year = delta.readLine();
            int cYear = Integer.parseInt(Year);

            // prompts the user for the current month as a numeric value
            boolean validmonth = false;
            while(!validmonth) {
                System.out.println("Please enter the current month as a numeric value");
                String Month = delta.readLine();
                cMonth = Integer.parseInt(Month);

                if(cMonth < 1 || cMonth > 12) {
                    System.out.println("Your input was invalid");
                } else {
                    validmonth = true;
                }
            }

            // prompts the user for the current day as a numeric value
            boolean validday = false;

            while(!validday) {
                System.out.println("Please enter the current day as a numeric value");
                String Day = delta.readLine();
                cDay = Integer.parseInt(Day);

                if(cDay < 1) {
                    System.out.println("Your input was invalid");
                } else if(cDay > 31) {
                    System.out.println("Your input was invalid");
                } else if(cMonth == 4 && cDay > 30) {
                    System.out.println("Your answer is invalid");
                } else if(cMonth == 6 && cDay > 30) {
                    System.out.println("Your answer is invalid");
                } else if(cMonth == 9 && cDay > 30) {
                    System.out.println("Your answer is invalid");
                } else if(cMonth == 11 && cDay > 30) {
                    System.out.println("Your answer is invalid");
                } else {
                    validday = true;
                }
            }

            // prompts the user for their birth year
            boolean validYear = false;
            while(!validYear) {
                System.out.println("Please enter your birth year");
                String Year2 = delta.readLine();
                bYear = Integer.parseInt(Year2);

                if(bYear > cYear) {
                    System.out.println("Your answer was invalid");
                } else {
                    validYear = true;
                }
            }
            // does not allow user to input a value greater than their current
            // year
            // loops if invalid

            // prompts the user for their birth month
            boolean _validmonth = false;
            while(!_validmonth) {
                System.out.println("Please enter your birth month as a numeric value");
                String Month2 = delta.readLine();
                bMonth = Integer.parseInt(Month2);

                if(bMonth < 1 || bMonth > 12) {
                    System.out.println("Your answer was invalid");
                } else {
                    _validmonth = true;
                }
            }

            // prompts the user for their birth day
            boolean _validday = false;
            while(!_validday) {
                System.out.println("Please enter the day you were born as a numeric value");
                String Day2 = delta.readLine();
                bDay = Integer.parseInt(Day2);
                // prints out collected data

                if(bMonth == 4 && bDay > 30) {
                    System.out.println("Your answer is invalid");
                } else if(bMonth == 6 && bDay > 30) {
                    System.out.println("Your answer is invalid");
                } else if(bMonth == 9 && bDay > 30) {
                    System.out.println("Your answer is invalid");
                } else if(bMonth == 11 && bDay > 30) {
                    System.out.println("Your answer is invalid");
                } else {
                    _validday = true;
                }
            }

            System.out.println("The current date is " + cMonth + "/" + cDay + "/" + cYear);
            System.out.println("Your birthday is " + bMonth + "/" + bDay + "/" + bYear);

            // calculates and prints age
            if(cMonth > bMonth) {
                int age = cYear - bYear;
                System.out.println("You are " + age + " years old ");
            } else if(cMonth < bMonth) {
                int age = cYear - bYear;
                System.out.println("You are " + age + " years old ");
            } else if(cMonth == bMonth && cDay > bDay) {
                int age = cYear - bYear;
                System.out.println("You are " + age + " years old.");
            } else if(cMonth == bMonth && cDay < bDay) {
                int age = cYear - bYear - 1;
                System.out.println("You are " + age + " years old. ");
            } else if(cYear == bYear) {
                System.out.println("You are not even a year old.");
            } else {

                System.out.println("Your input was invalid");
            }
        } catch(IOException IOE) {

        } catch(NumberFormatException NFE) {
            System.out.println("Please enter a numeric value without spaces, letters, or special characters");
        }
    }

    public static void retry() {
        BufferedReader delta = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        try {
            boolean valid = false;
            while(!valid) {
                System.out.println("Would you like to try again? 1) Yes or 2) No");
                System.out.println("Please enter a number");
                String retry = delta.readLine();
                int trynum = Integer.parseInt(retry);

                if(trynum < 1 || trynum > 2) {
                    System.out.println("Your input was invalid. Please enter 1 or 2.");
                    continue;
                } else if(trynum == 1) {
                    prompt();
                } else if(trynum == 2) {
                    System.out.println("Okay then.");
                    System.exit(0);
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Invalid");
                    continue;
                }
            }
        } catch(IOException IOE) {

        } catch(NumberFormatException NFE) {
            System.out.println("Please enter a number");
        }
    }
}
```